# Apache ProxyRequest

Tags: apache-2.2, php, proxy

I have an Apache server running on port 8888 in my dev environment. I would like to have my WebSocket server use the same port. (The reason is in the live environment it's not 8888 and we want every users to be able to use the websocket so port 80 is the best).

I thought that if I can proxy the call to 8888 to the internal WebSocket that is hosted to the port 12345 that the socket can works.

So far, I have enabled

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

I have added to my httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass ^serverWebSocket.php ws://localhost:12345/serverWebSocket.php
    ProxyPassReverse ^serverWebSocket.php ws://localhost:12345/serverWebSocket.php 
</VirtualHost>
```

The Javascript open a socket this way :

```
 socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/serverWebSocket.php");
```

I know the code Javascript and PHP server for websocket works because if I simply put the port 12345 directly it works. But now, I want to use from the external the port 8888.

What am I missing?

Comment: I suggest you rename this question so it has "WebSockets" in the title.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost:  **turn off ProxyRequests!**  This directive is for creating a proxy server that can be given requests for all sites on the internet; it **will** be found and used for things you don't want it doing if exposed to the net.

Anyway.. changing your `ProxyPass` (and matching reverse) should do the trick.  No regex here, and it uses absolute paths in the `<VirtualHost>` context.  If you need regex, you can use mod_rewrite, but it doesn't look like you do.

```
ProxyPass /serverWebSocket.php http://localhost:12345/serverWebSocket.php
ProxyPassReverse /serverWebSocket.php http://localhost:12345/serverWebSocket.php
```

Comment: I have removed the ProxyRequests On line. I have also modify to use  / instead of ^but still does not work. Is there a way to debug that?

Comment: Well.. I modified the answer, since `ws://` isn't valid to apache (definitely copy-pasted without looking at that part); try now.

Comment: Still not working. This is weird because even if Apache have not defined the ws protocol, if I unblock port 12345 I can make it works. Tonight I'll update the question with more detail.

Comment: I just thought about it, I think I'll have to change the Javascript to call this address : http://localhost:8888/serverWebSocket.php and the proxy will change it to ws://localhost:12345/serverWebSocket.php, what do you think?

Comment: The problem is at the Javascript Socket. When I put the URL that should be proxy, it crash. But if I put the old code with the ws://... it works. I do not know if the proxy work well because it take the http: to create the ws: so it should work >.<

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use Apache 2.4, and use its mod_proxy_wstunnel module.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html

I would even think it preferable to have you API endpoint on a different hostname (eg. api.example.com versus www.example.com), which would mean that you can separate you API traffic from non-API traffic, and use infrastructure that was suitable for each. (Example: I have recently heard that the Varnish crowd have released a product like varnish but for API management --- and that's about all I know of that at present).

I wouldn't be comfortable having Apache (2.2 at least, which is what I use) be serving up an API endpoint due to C10K concerns.

Comment: Here's a description of backporting mod_proxy_wstunnel to Apache 2.2